# Why I am getting Error: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have 3 models

```
class Lease(CommonInfo):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    #amount  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    is_renewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)
    is_terminated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class LeaseTerm(CommonInfo):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    start_period = models.ForeignKey(Period, related_name='start_period' )
    end_period = models.ForeignKey(Period, related_name='end_period')
    lease = models.ForeignKey(Lease)
    increase  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    amount  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    is_terminated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def clean(self):
    model = self.__class__
    if self.lease_id and (self.is_terminated == False) and model.objects.filter(lease=self.lease, is_active=True ).count() == 1:
        raise ValidationError('!Lease has a active condition already, Terminate prior to creation of new one'.format(self.lease))

class LeasePayment(CommonInfo):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    amount  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    leaseterm = models.ForeignKey(LeaseTerm)
    period_payed_for = models.DateTimeField()
    payment_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

(clean method allows only one LeaseTerm to be active and not terminated.)

In my view I want to see all the payments done for this Lease   of its active  LeaseTerm

```
    lease = get_object_or_404(Lease, pk=lease_id)
    leaseterm = LeaseTerm.objects.filter(lease=lease, is_terminated =False, is_active = True )
    payment = leaseterm.leasepayment_set.all().order_by('payment_date')
```

but getting an error

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'leasepayment_set'

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

an instance of the model `LeaseTerm` has the attribute `leasepayment_set`, not a queryset of the model `LeaseTerm`. You may access to `leasepayment_set` by getting the instance like these.

1. `get` instead of `filter`

   ```
   leaseterm = LeaseTerm.objects.get(lease=lease, ...)
   payment = leaseterm.leasepayment_set.all()
   ```
2. looping around the queryset

   ```
   leaseterm = LeaseTerm.objects.filter(lease=lease, ...)
   for lt in leaseterm: # lt is an instance of LeaseTerm
       payment = lt.leasepayment_set.all()
   ```
3. (Updated via comments, thanks to Alasdair and Ingomar) starting with the related model, and it is more efficient and elegant query expression.

   ```
   LeasePayment.objects.filter(leaseterm__lease=lease)
   ```

Comment: There's a third option that might be useful in this case: create a `LeasePayment` queryset and use the double underscore notation to filter on lease: `payments = LeasePayment.objects.filter(leaseterm__lease=lease)`

Comment: I'd recommend to use the option given by Alasdair. If you have a large dataset this will use less queries. Actually, even with a small dataset. But the performance benefit will be noticeable with large datasets;)